# how to pattern match over multiple column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet with two column-first column with some number and second column with the values for various other number including specified numbers in column one. The values in second column are present along with other values in comma separated format and the specified number is quoted in bracket. How do I extract the value for the specified number is column 1 from second column?
For instance:

The data I have:

[image]

Output required:

[image]

Looking forward for reply and Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the formula(e) you have tried and if not obvious, share the locations of the data.

Comment: I tried text to column command to separate the values in column 2 and used following formula with hope to get the value containing specified number in bracket-  =IF(SUM(COUNTIF(B1:H1,{A1})),"yes","")

Comment: Why is `13356818` => `0` but `764249837` =>`9.75E-1;1.134E-3;0.0`?  IOW, why do you include the semicolon separated values in line 3 but not in line 1?

Comment: Um sorry semicolon supposed to be there both mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 365, and your data is in columns A and B, you can use:

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(B1,","),
y, MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND(A1,x)),0),
z, TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(x,y),"("),
INDEX(z,1))
```

If you have an earlier version of Excel (Windows), you can use:

```
=LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.," & A1 & ")]"), FIND("(",FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.," & A1 & ")]"))-1)
```